# Multiple timeMeasureStarts with a single timeMeasureEnd

Tags: anylogic

I know that it is possible to add multiple timeMeasureStart blocks into the list of one timeMeasureEnd block. The model runs without errors. However, is there a way to obtain data for each timeMeasureStart block separately using that one timeMeasureEnd block?

For example, say there are multiple timeMeasureStart blocks: A, B, C located at different points in a flowchart. I have one timeMeasureEnd block at the end named Z. I know you can add A, B, C into the list of Z. However how can we obtain the average, max, min, count for A, B, C separately?

Thanks

I tried having a single timeMeasureEnd with multiple timeMeasureStart blocks added into the list, however all I am getting is a single number for mean, min, max, count, not knowing which timeMeasureStart it is reading from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not, they are merged into one. Start measuring in different ways, these blocks are just simple helpers. You can log stuff in variables, collections, etc. if you need to trace specifics. Check the example models for some guidance